# Delete the bottom half of a geometry along the Z-axis using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, axis

I just can't figure it out why it does not delete half of a mesh. Trying to do so in geometry nodes.

I want to delete the bottom half of it along the Z-axis but I can't, it acts like it has only 6 faces, these subdivided faces aren't helping at all.

Normals of new faces do not seem correct, I don't know why. It's like there is only 3 states for faces: -1, 1, nearly 0.

[image: The figure, does not work]

If I do it with UV sphere it works

[image: Sphere, works]

Comment: Why _Normal_? Why not _Position_?

Comment: I didn't actually know what are the normals, but now I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the lower half of the geometry, I would use the input node `Position` instead of the input node `Normal`:

[image]

The normals of the faces are definitely not the right way here, because they always point away from a face with a unit vector, and thus do not provide useful values for a position comparison on the *Z-axis*.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it helped